# Unable to assign selected value to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I have added a combobox to added new static values to that as..

On XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbBoxControlTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ComboBox>
```

On Code Behind Page Load:

```
MMVVMControl.cmbBoxControlTypes.Items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Text Box", "0"));
MMVVMControl.cmbBoxControlTypes.Items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Pick List", "1"));
MMVVMControl.cmbBoxControlTypes.Items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Check Box", "2"));
```

On Edit:

```
MMVVMControl.cmbBoxControlTypes.SelectedValue = dtDataList.Rows[0]["Controls"].ToString();
```

After assigning the selected value I am getting null.
Please someone tell me how can I solve this.

Comment: What is the value of `dtDataList.Rows[0]["Controls"]`

Comment: I am getting value of dtDataList.Rows[0]["Controls"] = "0" as I have saved same in database table

Comment: Can you put the code for your `CustomComboBoxItem` class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your responses: I have added

```
DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="Value"
```

to my combobox and got the solution.